# Ejemplo de sharding en mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Alguien me puede ayudar a realizar un balanceo de carga en mongodb, estoy siguiendo este tutorial de sharding https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/sharding-en-mongodb/ pero justo al inicio después de ejecutar el comando

```
 cluster = new ShardingTest({shards : 3, chunksize : 1})
```

ya me sale este error y no entiendo porque... cualquier orientación o guía se aprecia mucho seguiré mirando por mi cuenta :)[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

te pongo una guía paso a paso para crear varios shards e instancias de MongoDB en una única máquina (evidentemente, para hacer esto en múltiples nodos, habría que hacer algunos cambios)

1- En primer lugar nos vamos a la ruta donde vamos a trabajar y creamos directorios para guardar nuestros datos:

```
mkdir shard_ejemplo
cd shard_ejemplo
mkdir s0_0 s0_1 s1_0 s1_1 config_0 config_1
```

2- Creados los directorios, levantamos los servidores que van a mantener los datos de configuración de nuestro clúster:

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath config_0 --port 26050 --logpath log.cfg0 --logappend --replSet configRS --fork
mongod --configsvr --dbpath config_1 --port 26051 --logpath log.cfg1 --logappend --replSet configRS --fork
```

3- Levanto 4 servidores mongo, 2 para un shard (con su réplica set) y 2 para el otro (OJO, no usar nunca en producción número par de nodos en un shard, si necesitas un factor de replicación de 2, mete un árbitro). Las configuraciones de `--smallfiles` y `--oplogSize` están puestas porque creo un entorno "de juguete"

```
mongod --shardsvr --replSet S0 --dbpath s0_0 --logpath log.s0_0 --port 27000 --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --fork
mongod --shardsvr --replSet S0 --dbpath s0_1 --logpath log.s0_1 --port 27001 --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --fork
mongod --shardsvr --replSet S1 --dbpath s1_0 --logpath log.s1_0 --port 27100 --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --fork
mongod --shardsvr --replSet S1 --dbpath s1_1 --logpath log.s1_1 --port 27101 --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --fork
```

4- Levantamos mongos, que va a actuar de "resolutor" de peticiones, indicándole dónde debe consultar la configuración de nuestro clúster:

```
mongos --configdb configRS/localhost:26050,localhost:26051 --logpath log.mongos0 --logappend --port 27017 --fork
```

(Esto está usando la configuración de localhost para todo, recuerda cambiarlo si no es tu caso)

4- Inicializar Réplica Set del ConfigServer:

```
mongo --port 26050
rs.initiate()
rs.add("localhost:26051")
```

4.1: Como probablemente el Replica Set se crease con el nombre del host, y estamos usando localhost, cambiar el nodo 0 a localhost:

```
cfg=rs.config()
cfg.members[0].host="localhost:26050"
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

5: Inicializar SHARDS,Nos conectamos a mongos y hacemos:

```
mongos
db=connect("localhost:27000/test")
rs.initiate()
```

Esto es para cambiar el hostname por localhost,

```
cfg=rs.config()
cfg.members[0].host="localhost:27000"
rs.reconfig(cfg)

rs.add("localhost:27001") 

db=connect("localhost:27017/test")
sh.addShard("S0/localhost:27000");
```

6: Repetimos para SHARD 2,Nos conectamos a mongos y hacemos:

```
mongos
db=connect("localhost:27100/test")
rs.initiate()
```

Esto es para cambiar el hostname por localhost,

```
cfg=rs.config()
cfg.members[0].host="localhost:27100"
rs.reconfig(cfg)

rs.add("localhost:27101")
db=connect("localhost:27017/test")
sh.addShard("S1/localhost:27100");
```

Con esto ya deberías tener creado un clúster, con un servidor mongos que ataca a dos config servers para obtener la información del clúster, que está formado por dos shards, cada uno con dos nodos.

Un saludo